# Why is this opto isolator input turning off so slowly?

Tags: transistors, opto-isolator

I feed a nice square wave into Q1/2, and on U40/1 I see a full turn off take almost a millisecond! What is happening, and can I fix it (ideally by not adding components)?

[image]

Comment: Your image link is broken

Comment: Do you mean the input or the output of U40? And if the output, how are you measuring those uncommitted pins? Show the complete circuit, please.

Comment: @WhatRoughBeast It is the signal on U40 pin 1 that is taking almost a ms to turn off fully

Comment: @Sclrx It renders OK in my Chrome browser

Comment: See figure 7 of U40's data sheet. How long does it take for the voltage to reach 1.5 volts? That is what counts.

Comment: @WhatRoughBeast It switches on in a few microseconds at pin 1, and almost a millisecond to turn off ie fall to 0V

Comment: I didn't ask that. I asked how long it takes to reach 1.5 volts. See the data sheet. Please answer the question asked, not something else.

Comment: I did a lot of tests with MIDI (31,250 baud) and some opto isolators are faster/usable ... like H11L1 or 6N138 compared to 6N137. So maybe you have to change the opto couplers you use.

Comment: @WhatRoughBeast About 3 microseconds

Comment: Are you saying that if you put a scope on PB19/PWM0 and a scope on U40 pin1 at the same time,  U40 pin1 follows PB19/PWM0 by 1 millisecond? If so,  I'd like to see the traces for a low-high transition and a high-low transition. If not,  I'd like to know how you are measuring your 1ms timing.

Comment: @vicatcu No. U40/1 has a decay curve that hits zero after about a millisecond. The output has a similar decay curve. No idea what the delay between the two is, but that is not the problem.

Comment: Can we see this "decay curve"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is some capacitance associated with the input. When the transistor turns off, this capacitance must be discharged through the LED of opto. As the data sheet suggests, at an input of about 1.5 volts the LED will turn off, and the output will switch. As you have determined, this takes about 3 usec, and you should compare this to the output delay. (Hint: they are pretty close to the same.)

Once the voltage drops below about 1.5 volts, the exponential nature of LED voltage/current means that the LED will start drawing less current, and rate of voltage drop will be reduced. At very low voltages the current will become very low indeed. This will lead to a long "tail" on the input voltage, as you see.

Try adding a 1k resistor from the input to ground, and see if that doesn't speed things up. There is no need to do this for an operational circuit, since it only cares about the voltage above about 1.5 volts, but try it anyways just to see what happens.

Comment: I reckon you've nailed this one +1